# Как реализовать структуру приложения?

Tags: swift, структуры, tableview

Подскажите как организовать такое приложение?
То есть это TableView внутри TableView? Или как то иначе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая минимальная версия iOS? Может все же SwiftUI вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идеальное и самое простое решение с помощью UICollectionView c использованием лэйаута: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

Самый простой пример где это можно увидеть -> AppStore

[Документация Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout)

[Статья на русском](https://habr.com/ru/post/495076/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]